# Ensuring integrity of broadcast messages between known network nodes

Tags: network, hmac, integrity

I need to share data between N network nodes in a given network.
The N network nodes are all mine, but apart from them it is possible for any device to connect to the same network.

There is no master node, all the nodes are on the same level. Any one of the nodes can generate the critical message that I want to protect the integrity of.

The solution that I have so far is storing a symmetrical secret in all my network nodes, and then send the messages (and a time stamp), one by one to each of my network nodes, along with an HMAC  value.
This will make sure that the messages cannot be replicated or retransmitted.

Is there a better way than using HMAC? Is there a way to use broadcast messages? (Create an internal network mask and send the messages as broadcast?)
Any comments on my suggested solution are welcome, thank you.

Comment: Would it be possible to use a message queue?

Comment: @YorickdeWid It probably is possible to use a message queue, can you please explain how a message queue is relevant to the implementation of the solution?

Comment: It would allow you to establish a secure connection to a master node once. Then all traffic can be send over this channel.

Comment: @YorickdeWid Yes it can be possible using a master node, but I do not have a master node, all the nodes are on the same level, any one of them can generate the critical message that I want to protect the integrity of. I will update my question accordingly, thank you.

Comment: @YorickdeWid After Aria's answer I understood what you meant, I will just add a server running a message queue, thanks

Comment: Message queues are beyond the scope of this board, so I didn't bother going into details. Arias answer does some explaining indeed

Answer (score 1):

Using broadcast messages (or multicast) is usable for continuous streams like 100 status updates per second and distributing it to thousands of nodes in real-time. It is also good for streaming video. Now the thing is that in this scenario some packets can be dropped and often never recovered as it's one-way communication.

Another thing is that if every node can send message to every another node it is very inefficient. This is because for N nodes you have N^2 connections / streams to manage, and for example if one node get glitchy all is slowing down, or if there are plenty of nodes it's also slowing down, as doing messaging on one's own is not as efficient and reliable as it is with mature software plus the architecture is inefficient too.

So the most optimal solution is to use message queue, the way you deploy additional nodes and their role is to serve as message brokers. So every instance would be able to send message to them and receive messages from it. This way you can use TLS and username/password to connect to the message server (and your nodes can make sure that remote TLS cert is the right one). Ideally you could also create dedicated VLAN for this so no-one can connect to it by plugging something.

Example servers:

- [rabbitmq](https://www.rabbitmq.com/)
- [activemq](http://activemq.apache.org/)
- [more of them on queues.io](http://queues.io/)

You can also use standard SQL Database, for example MariaDB, PostrgeSQL, SQL Server, Oracle DB etc. Since these databases have table level and sometimes row-level locking as well transaction isolation they are excellent for messaging. And now, if you are fearing that someone can connect to VLAN and pose as the database you do really need to put this on dedicated VLAN.

You can use any Layer 2/3 switch which can act as default gateway and has VLAN support.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make explanations clearer, let's suppose that this is some kind of distributed storage where a message would be

> “Who has file A? Please send it to me.”

and the node with file would send it to the sender. You want to protect the message so that devices outside your network are not able to fetch content from your network or alter it.

The timestamping is not a complete solution by itself since, by definition, there will be a (however small) window in which the message must be accepted. The other nodes must check that "now" is no later than X time after it was generated, but X shall be non-zero (so that the real message can arrive).
*[There is another kind of problems in keeping synchronised clocks on a distributed network, which will require an extra margin in the field]*

The timestamped message would be “It's $DATE. Who has file A? Please send it to me.” Simply adding a HMAC to the message wouldn't really protect it.

Inside that small time window, another node could also send

> “It's $DATE. Who has file A? Please send it to me.”

(copying the same HMAC), so it's clearly not enough.

However, if you are including who you are in the calculation, it's different (it could be added implicitly, or simply stated in the message): “It's $DATE. I'm 10.10.10.10. Who has file A? Please send it to 10.10.10.10 at port 9000.”

Still, you must also protect the answer so that your reply actually comes from an evil node. For example, communication at port 9000 could begin with:

> “I am 10.10.10.12 connecting to 10.10.10.10. I do have file A you asked for at $DATE. It is 123 bytes long and has SHA256 aabbccdd…” || HMAC

If the node didn't ask for file A at $DATE, or the file contents don't match the given hash, it should discard what it received.

An attacker could duplicate the request (or it could get duplicated by the network), potentially making 10.10.10.12 send the same information to 10.10.10.10 many times. It could filter it based on the request header shown above, but it's better to provide an identifier to differentiate duplicate replies, to answers to a repeated query (for instance, the querying node might be reading the same file continuously, because it will change shortly).

> “This is query 987654 at $DATE. I'm 10.10.10.10. Who has file A? Please send it to 10.10.10.10 at port 9000.” || HMAC

The querying node would simply need to remember the queries sent in the last 2*X time period approximately, and marking as Ongoing/Completed as needed. Any answer not matching a pending query could be discarded.

(Preferably, the identifier would be a random one, although the HMAC protects you from reply spoofing)

At this point, the integrity of the messages is protected by the HMAC secret, and you are protected against replays, you could send the queries in broadcast quite confident.

However, I should note that your network is based on a shared secret between the nodes. What would happen should one of them be compromised?

A more robust approach would be to use asymmetric keys on each node. Basically, you create keys for each node, and a local CA that signs each of them. Store on the nodes a copy of the public key of the CA and an -initially empty- revocation list.

Modify the above messages to replace the `HMAC(message, secret)` operation with `SIGN(message) || MyPublicKey`, and make your nodes trust the message if it comes correctly signed by a key signed by your local CA, and not in the revocation list.

(You may ignore the revocation list if you prefer to replace the CA —and public keys signed by it— in case a key was compromised)